# jQuery making adiv tag with muiltiple parameters how to use Quotes inside

Tags: jquery, html, quotes

If I have "" with single quotes inside, it shows F3-R06, but the move over and mouse out do not work.
if I take this out of the jQuery it works fine, but how to I use the quotes inside it does nothing.
What kind of quoting do I need inside ""?
I tried "" and this """ but nothing works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function drawdiv()
    {
        $("<div onmouseover="mOver(this,'Fred Flintstone')"  onmouseout="mOut(this,'F3-R06')" style='background-color:#D94A38;width:30px;height:30px;padding:20px'>F3-R06</div>").appendTo("body"); 
    })
</script>
<script>

function mOver(obj,name)
    {
        obj.innerHTML=name
    }

function mOut(obj,room)
    {
        obj.innerHTML=room
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate problems with quotes there. One is the jQuery selector quotes and the other the quotes within the div's js attributes.

First, by convention, consider using single quote inside of jQuery selectors so that you can use double quotes as needed for HTML attributes and the like.

```
$('<div id="this-is-fine"></div>').blah();
```

Second, when you *have* to have more than two quote types in the selector, you can escape them with a backslash(\).

```
$('<div onmouseover="mOver(this,\'Fred Flintstone\')"  onmouseout="mOut(this,\'F3-R06\')" style="background-color:#D94A38;width:30px;height:30px;padding:20px">F3-R06</div>').appendTo('body');
```

Third, maybe consider drinking a little more of the jQuery Kool-Aid.

```
jQuery('<div>F3-R06</div>')
    .attr('onmouseover', 'mOver(this, "Fred")')
    .attr('onmouseout', 'mOver(this, "F3-R06")')
    .css({ 
        'background-color' : '#D94A38', 
        'width' : '30px',
        'height' : '30px',
        'padding' : '20px'
        })
    .appendTo('body');
```

Slightly more kool-aid gets you here:

```
$('<div data-alt-text="Fred">F3-R06</div>')
    .hover(function (){ //first is mouseenter
        altText($(this));
    },
    function () { // second is mouseleave
        altText($(this)); 
    })
    .addClass('f3-box') // css is handy.
    .appendTo('body');

function altText ($obj){
    var text = $obj.text();
    // wang dang and reverse it - ms elliot
    $obj.text( $obj.attr('data-alt-text') );
    $obj.attr('data-alt-text', text )
}    

<style>
    .f3-box{
        background-color: #D94A38, 
        width: 30px,
        height: 30px,
        padding: 20px
    }
</style>
```

More on [.hover() in the jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Thank you Will, I tried the "Second, when you have to have more than two quote types in the selector" which worked perfect, thank you. I'll look at the other "kool-aid" items shortly. And since I only have 13 points I can't "up vote" yet, need 15 to do that, but I gave a green check :)

Comment: Also the goal here is to have a Database driving the "Fred Flintsone" and the room # "F3-R06". How would I incorporate that. Or since this is jQuery and you should'nt connect to SQL client side, then I need to do this in another language, I suspect?

Comment: You can't connect directly to a database with jquery. You can load a server generated page via the ajax() method(s). Or have your server output html like the original div you create and then use a jquery selector to get them all and attach this stuff. So presuming the Fred divs were already on the page, you'd change `$('<div data-alt-text="Fred">F3-R06</div>')` to `$('div')`. Output the HTML elements with a class so you can use a more specific selector. `<div class="freds" data-alt-text="Fred">F3-R06</div>` and then `$('.freds').hover(...)`.